# ACTION_DRAG_STARTED in draglistener is never called for first time android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I am having two Draglisteners

```
 Listener A it is placeholder to drop a particular item into it.(LinearLayout)
 Listener B the item which is being drop.(its a relative layout)
```

When i drag the relative layout it is drawing the shadow but when dropped resulting false.

I set the visiblity View.VISIBLE of LinearLayout only when the relative layout is being dragged.

The draglistener code for linearlayout

```
 @Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent dragevent) {

    switch (dragevent.getAction()) {

    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
        break;

    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                     // setting background
        break;
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:

        break;

    case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                     // updating my view
        break;

    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But only for the first time the DROP result is false from the second time it is working correct. And I set the draglistener when the activity created. Can anyone help me in this.